# Matlab source code for an existing spreadsheet model

Tags: excel, matlab

i am doing a project in mat lab where i am dealing with large amount of data. i Need create a source code for an existing model from spreadsheet where the computation has done row by row in the spreadsheet.I have problem writing the code for last 5 column of the spreadsheet where the result for the second row of the first column is going to use the result from first row of the fifth column and so on.
For information,

1. dh/dx is the 1st column
2. GWFLOW is the 2nd column
3. GWDROP is the 3rd column
4. NETGWCHANGE is the 4th column
5. REVGW is the 5th column

Screenshot of the excel file for clear view
[image: Excel file]

Here is the code that i did:

```
     %% dh/dx
     dh_dx=zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
     % for the first row
     dh_dx(1)=(ingwl-effecbase)/meandx;
     %for the remaining dh/dx
        for s=2:numel(HER);
            dh_dx(s)=(REVGW(s-1)-effecbase)/meandx;
        end

     %% GW flow for unit width
     GWFLOW=zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
     for t=1:numel(HER);
         GWFLOW(t)=K*dh_dx(t)*aqb;
     end

   %% Drop of GW due to GW flow
   GWDROP=zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
   for u=1:numel(HER);
       GWDROP(u)=(GWFLOW(u)/(aqb*por));
   end

   %% Net Groundwater change
   NETGWCHANGE=zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
   for v=1:numel(HER);
       NETGWCHANGE(v)=INCGW(v)-GWDROP(v);
   end

   % Revised GW level Estimate
   REVGW=zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
   %for the first row
   REVGW(1)=ingwl+NETGWCHANGE(1);
   for w=2:numel(HER);
       REVGW(w)=REVGW(w-1)+NETGWCHANGE(w)
   end
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: High rep users can edit your images in. Just add the links in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you calculate in your code all the data separatedly, while it needs to be computed all-together, in the same loop:

```
    % Allocate data
    dh_dx       = zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
    GWFLOW      = zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
    GWDROP      = zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
    NETGWCHANGE = zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);
    REVGW       = zeros(numel(rocky.RAIN),1);

    % Seed the calculation on the first row
    dh_dx(1)       = (ingwl-effecbase)/meandx;
    GWFLOW(1)      = K*dh_dx(1)*aqb;
    GWDROP(1)      = (GWFLOW(1)/(aqb*por));
    NETGWCHANGE(1) = INCGW(1)-GWDROP(1);
    REVGW(1)       = ingwl + NETGWCHANGE(1);

    % Loop trough the other rows and calculate fields
    for s = 2:numel(HER)
            dh_dx(s)       = (REVGW(s-1)-effecbase)/meandx;
            GWFLOW(s)      = K*dh_dx(s)*aqb;
            GWDROP(s)      = GWFLOW(s)/(aqb*por);
            NETGWCHANGE(s) = INCGW(s) - GWDROP(s);
            REVGW(s)       = REVGW(s-1) + NETGWCHANGE(s);
    end;
```